# Team Foundation Service Sign-In window in vs2012 stays blank but status is 'Done'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

When I try to connect with my VS2012 with [project].visualstudio.com, the sign-in window that pops up says it is connecting and then it stays blank as you can see in the picture below:

[image: Blank sign-in windows Team Foundation Service]

I tryed the following but didn't help:

- Set IE as my default browser;
- Cleared the IE browser history: Temp files, Cookies, History and
  Passwords;
- Cleared the tfs server list in vs2012;
- Cleared the credential manager entries in Windows 7;
- Manually add the tfs service to vs2012.

As you can guess, I cannot sign-in tfs from vs2012.

With kind regards,

Cees van Altena

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? I'm stick now with the same issue. :(

Comment: Ok, I got it to work clearing history (all options checked) in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using CCleaner after I updated with the patch. Sometimes it doesn't load the login screen for some reason. I believe there was information on an official patch for this issue [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2662296) and download the patch [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082).

Comment: The official patch you mention is about VS 2010 SP1. The question is about VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways worked for me:

1. Add below url in Trusted Sites

> https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com

2. Open the same url in IE and do login first and then try connecting the server from Visual Studio.